# Handle signal from 'kill -3' or taskkill in Win32Console application

Tags: perl, console-application

I have a Win32 console application (built from Visual Studio as Win32 console project) which does some log file (.txt) processing. I have a separate perl program (legacy program) which now needs to start this Win32 console application and then stop when done.

Perl program starts an instance of Win32 console app using Win32::Process APIs. It can kill the console app when done by either "kill -x pid" or Win32:Process:Kill. The problem is console app needs to know if its being killed/terminated so that it can flush log handling. The console app has already registered a handler via SetConsoleCtrlHandler API but doesn't get called when killed from perl program by say kill -2/3 pid.

- What do I change in perl program or in Win32 console app so that it can know when its being terminated?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Signal handling in Windows is a little quirky if you're used to Unix. I have done a lot of investigation into this, and wrote up my findings [here](https://metacpan.org/source/MOB/Forks-Super-0.71/lib/Forks/Super/Job/OS/Win32.pm) (starting at line 261).

Short answer: Windows processes can set `$SIG{INT}`, `$SIG{QUIT}`, or `$SIG{BREAK}`. All other signal handlers are ignored. Signal them from you separate app with the builtin [`kill`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#kill):

```
kill 'INT', $the_win32_logger_pid;
kill 'QUIT', $the_win32_logger_pid;
kill 'BREAK', $the_win32_logger_pid;
```

Comment: Thanks mob. Anything I need to do in Win32 console app so that it receives this signal? Or is just a handler set from SetConsoleCtrlHandler good enough? I am not having much success with just kill 'QUIT' pid? The console app does not seem to receive the signal:(

Comment: I was under the impression that the console app was a Perl program; then you could set `$SIG{QUIT}` in the console app and exit gracefully. But maybe I was mistaken?

Comment: Perl program is a legacy software which in turn starts and stops the win32 console application. The console application (the one which mucks with logs) is a Visual Studio built project as "Win32 console application".

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of my depth, then. My answer applies to one Perl program on Windows signalling another Perl program on Windows.

Comment: Ok, thanks for attempting though. I have clarified my question above to indicate console app is Visual Studio built one.